# atan(location1 - location2) returns an incorrect value

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to calculate the angle that one entity would have to look at to look at another entity.

`l` is the location of the first entity.

`o` is the location of the other entity.

Each entity has a 3D X, Y, and Z coordinate in a 3D space.

I currently calculate the X and Z into degrees correctly, using `double angXZ = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(((l.getZ()) - o.getZ()), ((l.getX()) - o.getX())));`.

However, when I try to turn the Y into degrees, it gives completely wrong readings.

I currently am trying to use `double angY = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(l.getY() - o.getY()));` to get the angle in degrees between the two Y coordinates, but it just doesn't seem to be working.

Why not? What is going wrong here? And how can I fix it?

The end goal is to be able to step through all coordinates between the first entity and the second one and check if there are any objects in between.

As an example, `Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(51 - 50));` is equalling 58, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: can you state your input and output? is it wrong all of the time?

Comment: What do you mean by the "angle [...] between the two Y coordinates"?  Those are just two real numbers: how do they determine an angle?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Think of them being Y coordinates in a 3D space. If you look at the end goal, it makes sense.

Comment: Not to me, I'm afraid.  You're subtracting one Y coordinate from another and trying to interpret that as the tangent of an angle?  Which angle?

Comment: *As an example, `Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(51 - 50));` is equalling 58, which is clearly not correct.* I cannot reproduce this behaviour. This exact equation yields the result `45.0` for me (which is correct). Which JDK and which version exactly do you use? I tested with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45.

Comment: You need three points to define an angle. Where's your third point? Presumably the origin (0,0,0) ?

Comment: @MarkDickinson The angle I am looking for is the pitch that entity1 would have to look at to be looking at entity2 in 3D space. I have already correctly calculated the yaw, and now I need the pitch.

Comment: @Joehot200: Ah, okay.  That makes sense.  So you're looking for the angle between (1) the line through your two points and (2) the x-z coordinate plane.  In that case, I think you want `Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y_diff, distance))`, where `y_diff` is the difference in y-coordinates (as you're already computing), and `distance` is the distance from the first point to the second in the x-z plane.  You should be able to compute the latter quantity as `Math.hypot(x_diff, z_diff)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you so much! It works. The question is, why? Is it possible that you could post an answer explaining what exactly that's doing and why that works? I'm a home-educated 15 year-old, so I'd really appreciate the extra knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you're trying to compute the angle between (1) the line through the points `l` and `o`, and (2) the XZ-plane. Let's refer to the Y-direction as vertical.  Then you're going to need two pieces of information: the horizontal distance from `l` to `o` (that is, the distance between the two points after projection to the XZ-plane), and the vertical distance from `l` to `o` (the difference in Y-coordinates).  As it stands, it looks as though you're trying to compute the angle based on just the vertical difference.  That's obviously problematic: the difference in height between the two points isn't going to be enough to determine the angle you're after.

The horizontal difference you need can be computed using `Math.hypot` and the differences in X and Z coordinates.  So your code to compute the angle would look something like the following:

```
/* Compute the components of the vector from o to l. */
double diffX = l.getX() - o.getX();
double diffY = l.getY() - o.getY();
double diffZ = l.getZ() - o.getZ();

/* Find the horizontal distance from o to l (assuming that
   Y is the vertical direction. */
double distXZ = Math.hypot(diffX, diffZ);

/* Compute the angle in degrees using the vertical distance
   and the horizontal distance. */
double pitch = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(diffY, distXZ));
```

Comment: Oh, right, you posted an answer - I hadn't noticed. I'd really appreciate it if you could explain a bit more as to *why* that works, if it isn't too much trouble for you. Thank you.

Comment: @Joehot200: Hmm.  To explain better, I really need to be able to draw a right-angled triangle.  Let me try to put it in words: you've got two points L and O.  Make a 3rd point P, where P is directly above (or below) L, but on the same horizontal level as O.  Now look at the triangle O-P-L.  O-P is purely horizontal, and has length `distXZ`.  P-L is purely vertical, and has length the absolute value of `diffY`.  Now a bit of trigonometry should convince you that the angle you want is the inverse tan of P-L / O-P, which is what the `atan2` call is computing (with appropriate handling of signs).